# How to fix SSLHandshakeException

Tags: web-services, ssl, wsdl, oim, oracle-enterprise-manager

We are getting the below error when i try to parse the wsdl in Enterprise manager. How do i fix this.

The WSDL document could not be parsed.The following error occured while parsing the WSDL location - WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "https:/xxx?WSDL", caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException.    : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: you need to include the top signing certificate into your trust keystore. What is the application you are using to access the wsdl URL?

Comment: What happens when you open the page from browser i mean the WSDL Url? Did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the required CA certificates are added into the required CERT db files like if the App/Web server using JDK's one then file should be ${JAVA_home}/jre/lib/security/cacerts.

You can cross check that your certificate is added or not.
keytool -list -keystore${JAVA_home}/jre/lib/security/cacerts

The keystore file path may vary based on your server configuration.